# Need a book title - deadly carnival

Tags: story-identification

YA genre. Teens go to carnival that appears in the town. As best I remember there is a female character who is one of those who runs the carnival.

Teens keep returning to it, compulsively, and eventually all but 2 (if I remember correctly) die on the rides.

**NOTE:** It's not *Something Wicked This Way Comes*. It is not a Ray Bradbury story.

Comment: Why did you add a Ray Bradbury tag is it's **not** his book? I've fixed that for you.

Comment: Can you recall when the book was written/published/ date it for us at all?

Comment: I recall a YA story I read a long time ago. (70s?) a boy  goes with a lot of his friends to a fairground that has rides that can be deadly. Quite a few people die every night on the rides. He choses to ride the most dangerous ride as his first ride. His friends ride other less deadly rides.  Although it terrified him, he survives the ride, while a few other people did not. He meets up with his friends who are amazed he survived. He then rides on one of the safest rides, but dies on it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate a time when you read the book. However, is this possibly the 2004 novel Full Tilt by Neal Shusterman?

Points that match are that it is mysterious carnival which attracts teens. It is run by a female character.

> ...he receives a ticket from Cassandra to another amusement park open at night.

The rides are dangerous:

> To Blake's horror, he discovers that if you "die" on a ride, you are absorbed into it.

There are also teens that are compulsively attracted to the rides and don't want to hear about danger.

> Here, he finds his brother Quinn and attempts to warn him of the dangers of the park. Quinn, enjoying the life-or-death thrill of the ride, refuses to believe Blake. As a result, Quinn runs away from Blake after finishing the ride.

At the end:

> The teens do eventually escape but more than just two.

A more detailed plot synopsis appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Tilt_(novel))

Cover looks like:

[image: Cover]